# Core plot : Updating labels using shouldUpdateAxisLabels and shouldUpdateMinorAxisLabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

This is a follow up question to.
[Core plot-Add OutOfRange to draw graph that changes dynamically with label "OL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582944/core-plot-add-outofrange-to-draw-graph-that-changes-dynamically-with-label-ol).

I am using Automatic labelling policy and using `shouldUpdateAxisLabels` and `shouldUpdateMinorAxisLabels` and trying to set the OL label for whichever location is the highest.

In that method,

```
//Check whether need to set labelling for minTickLocations or majorTickLocations
double maxMajorTickLocationValue = [[[axis.majorTickLocations allObjects] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"] doubleValue];
double minMajorTickLocationValue = [[[axis.majorTickLocations allObjects] valueForKeyPath:@"@min.doubleValue"] doubleValue];
double maxMinorTickLocationValue = [[[axis.minorTickLocations allObjects] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.doubleValue"] doubleValue];
double minMinorTickLocationValue = [[[axis.minorTickLocations allObjects] valueForKeyPath:@"@min.doubleValue"] doubleValue];
```

while setting labels, I check if location is highest location, for e.g., if location is in majorLocations array and if its greater than maxMinorLocation and set "OL". Similarly for min value with "-OL".

Issue I am facing here is, labelling will always happen on minor locations. So for eg., in case of UI if highest location is a major location and lowest is a minor location, setting of OL label to a major location and -OL to a minor location does not work and labels will be set to only minor locations. Attaching graph image as well.

So pls suggest.
/Users/shrikanth/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-01-02 at 7.23.06 AM.png

Comment: You need to post the screenshot somewhere online and link to it in the question if you don't have enough rep to post it directly in the question.

Comment: Are you labeling all of the minor tick marks, too, or just when one of them is the min or max OL value?